# Compare to list inside lambda expressions

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, lambda

I'm searching for a way to auto compare an object propriety to a list of values inside a lambda expression.
For example I have this lambda expression:

```
List<MyObjectType> myObjectList = GetObjectValues();

List<MyObjectType> filterdObjectList = myObjectList.Where(x => x.objectProp == ??a list of values??)
```

Basicly I need to filter my list of objects after the `"objectProp"` that can have multiple valid values.(Note: I do not want to use **`"Foreach"`**)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List<MyObjectType> myObjectList = GetObjectValues();

List<ValueType> valueList = GetValues();

List<MyObjectType> filterdObjectList =
             myObjectList.Where(x => valueList.Contains (x.objectProp))
```

Comment: The `Contains` call will have much better performance if you use a `HashSet<T>` for `valueList` instead of a `List<T>`.

Comment: Pay attention to the Luke's advice if you have lots of values to match against.